# Transpose/Pivot DataFrame but not all columns in the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` and I want to transpose it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[111,111,222,222,333,333],'Month':['Jan','Feb','Jan','Feb','Jan','Feb'],
                   'Employees':[2,3,1,5,7,1],'Subsidy':[20,30,10,15,40,5]})
print(df)
    ID Month  Employees  Subsidy
0  111   Jan          2       20
1  111   Feb          3       30
2  222   Jan          1       10
3  222   Feb          5       15
4  333   Jan          7       40
5  333   Feb          1        5
```

**Desired output:**

```
    ID        Var   Jan  Feb
0  111  Employees     2    3
1  111    Subsidy    20   30
0  222  Employees     1    5
1  222    Subsidy    10   15
0  333  Employees     7    1
1  333    Subsidy    40    5
```

*My attempt:* I tried using [`pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), but both `Employees` & `Subsidy` naturally appear in same rows, where as I want them on separate rows.

```
df.pivot_table(index=['ID'],columns='Month',values=['Employees','Subsidy'])

        Employees   Subsidy
Month    Feb  Jan  Feb  Jan
ID
111        3    2   30   20 
222        5    1   15   10 
333        1    7    5   40
```

I tried using [`transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), but it transposes entire `DataFrame`, it seems there is no possibility to transpose by first fixing a column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for set new column name for first level after pivoting and also `None` for avoid `Month` column name in final DataFrame, which is reshaped by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by first level, last MultiIndex in converted to coumns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df2 = (df.pivot_table(index='ID',
                     columns='Month',
                     values=['Employees','Subsidy'])
        .rename_axis(['Var',None], axis=1)
        .stack(level=0)
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df2)
    ID        Var  Feb  Jan
0  111  Employees    3    2
1  111    Subsidy   30   20
2  222  Employees    5    1
3  222    Subsidy   15   10
4  333  Employees    1    7
5  333    Subsidy    5   40
```

Comment: @cph_sto - there is necessary index `0,1,0,1` pattern?

Comment: You mean Jan, Feb, Jan,Feb?

Comment: @cph_sto - In `Desired output:` is `df.index` like `0,1,0,1,0,1`

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why we need to do stack(0), as that would be helpful. By the way, can we solve this problem using transpose()?

Comment: Well, you are a famous person on SO and I have seen people addressing you that way.

Comment: @cph_sto - hmmm, Not sure if famous, but thank you you for explanation ;)

Comment: Hi, this `.rename_axis(['Var',None], axis=1)` doesn't work with python `3.6.12`. I get `ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2`. .... Though, I can solve this issue indirectly, but thought to ask if it can be done in ths version directly...

Comment: @cph_sto - How working if remove it? `.rename_axis(['Var',None], axis=1)`

Comment: It works, then I get `index` column named `Month` and `var` has the old name `level_1`. Rest all is good.

Comment: @cph_sto -Can you test `.rename_axis('Var', axis=1)` ?

Comment: I did `df.pivot_table(.....).rename_axis('Var', axis=1).stack(level=0).reset_index()` got error `ValueError: Length of names must martch numbers of levels in Multiindex`

Comment: @cph_sto - I think I got it

Comment: @cph_sto - Use `.rename_axis(['Var','Month'], axis=1)` and then after my solution add `.rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Sorry a quick question if I may - if the `month` column would have been a `datetime` instead of string `Jan, Feb`, then is it guaranteed that the order of `month` columns after doing `pivot_table()..` will be increasing like first we will have `2020-01-01`, then `2020-02-01` column, then `2020-03-01` column and so on?

Comment: @cph_sto I think yes, pivoting sorting index and columns.

Answer (score 0):

You were on point with your `pivot_table` approach. Only thing is you missed `stack` and `reset_index` :

```
df.pivot_table(index=['ID'],columns='Month',values=['Employees','Subsidy']).stack(0).reset_index()

Out[42]: 
Month   ID    level_1  Feb  Jan
0      111  Employees    3    2
1      111    Subsidy   30   20
2      222  Employees    5    1
3      222    Subsidy   15   10
4      333  Employees    1    7
5      333    Subsidy    5   40
```

You can change the column name to `var` later if it's needed.